# Google compute machine HAXM install

Tags: google-compute-engine, haxm

I have a **Google Virtual Server**(*Microsoft Windows Server 2012*) and I would like to run *AVD with X86 Processor Setting*. I need to install **HAXM** but when I want to install it I get an error message.

**HAXM Install Error Message:**
[image]

Could anyone help me how can I install the HAXM on the Google virtual server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but nested virtualization (specifically, exposure of virtualized VT-x support, which is what HAXM is looking for) is not currently supported on Google Compute Engine. Unfortunately this is not mentioned anywhere in our documentation that I see, but it is in fact true.

A similar question was answered here: [Does Google Cloud services support nested virtual machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970525/)